# Como fazer previsão de valores de uma variável?

Tags: python, matlab, aprendizagem-de-máquina

Viva.

Eu não percebo muito ou mesmo nada de previsão de valores. O meu problema é saber como prever futuros valores de uma certa variável com base num conjunto de valores previamente anotados ...

Sabem onde posso encontrar tutorias que expliquem bem o que eu necessito de perceber e fazer para resolver o meu problema?

Obrigado!

EDIT:

Eu tenho medições de temperatura com intervalos regulares (neste caso é de 5 em 5 min mas também tenho de 10 em 10 min ou outros valores). Ex:

180   '2000-08-13 14:05:00'

172   '2000-08-13 14:10:00'

110   '2000-08-13 14:35:00'

102   '2000-08-13 14:40:00'

94    '2000-08-13 14:45:00'
....

O que eu queria saber é como é que posso determinar a temperatura futura com uma janela de 30 min, ou seja, fazer previsão da temperatura, por exemplo, no instante '2000-08-13 15:15:00'. Se precisarem de mais informações, avisem!

Também já procurei no google mas está difícil de perceber bem como estas coisas funcionam. Isto porque parece-me que o que vejo é do estilo: dado x e y o resultado vai ser z e no meu caso é dado q o resultado é q (se é que me faço entender).

Comment: Olá. Bem vindo. Ao invés de pedir por tutoriais, você poderia tentar explicar o seu problema em mais detalhes e solicitar ajuda diretamente. Pode começar expondo exemplos da sua variável e dos valores anotados. :)

Comment: Em todos os casos, o [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/) é uma biblioteca fantástica pra aprendizagem de máquina em Python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você ofereceu poucos exemplos do seu problema, então eu fiz o melhor que eu pude com eles. Ao menos nesses dados, a temperatura cai ao longo do dia de uma forma bastante linear. Assim, você pode tentar produzir um modelo linear (fazendo uma [regressão linear](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regress%C3%A3o_linear), usando o método dos mínimos quadrados como sugerido pelo @Vinicius) com os dados que tem e assim tentar prover o valor para uma hora mais adiantada.

Fiz um exemplo em Python com o [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/) (para a criação do modelo preditivo) e o [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) (para os gráficos), mas desconsiderando a data (mas você pode transformar a data completa em segundos [usando uma abordagem como essa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11489834/2896619))::

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model

# Carrega os seus dados
segundos_dia = np.array([[50700], [51000], [52500], [52800], [53100]]) 
temperatura  = np.array([180,   172,   110,   102,   94])

# Cria o modelo linear
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

# Treina o modelo com os dados de exemplo
regr.fit(segundos_dia, temperatura)

# Dados para previsao (isto eh, os segundos do dia)
segundos_prev = np.array([55320])

temp_prev = regr.predict(segundos_prev)
print('Previsto:')
print(temp_prev)

# Dados usados no treinamento
plt.scatter(segundos_dia, temperatura,  color='black')

plt.xlabel('Segundos do dia')
plt.ylabel('Temperatura')

plt.show()
```

Este exemplo resulta na seguinte saída:

```
Previsto:
8.11879699248
```

E no seguinte gráfico:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O horário utilizado para testar a predição foi 15:22 (55320 segundos do dia). Como você irá perceber, o preditor resultou na temperatura de aproximadamente 8 graus, e eu não sei se isso está correto para o seu problema. O fato é que no meu exemplo eu usei poucos dados em um intervalo bastante curto, e como você pode notar no gráfico a tendência é de queda acentuada. Por isso, para esses dados a resposta parece condizente.

Note também que no exemplo a matriz de segundos é bidimensional, e precisa ser assim porque o modelo aceita entradas com múltiplas variáveis para a definição da sua condição. De fato, quanto mais variáveis você tiver (além da informação do dia/hora), potencialmente mais preciso se torna o seu modelo de regressão. Porém, ai começam a entrar outros problemas (como, por exemplo, talvez o seu problema não seja realmente linear) e dificuldades (como a [maldição da dimensionalidade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality)).

P.S.: Esse exemplo é baseado no [próprio exemplo do scikit-learn (*ordinary least squares*)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#ordinary-least-squares). Lá você acha outros exemplos como o Bayes, também sugerido pelo Vinicius na resposta dele.

P.S.2: No mundo real, a variação da temperatura ao longo de vários dias dificilmente será linear (porque ela pode subir e descer ao longo de um dia, repetindo esse padrão nos dias seguintes). Nesse caso, talvez você possa usar uma [Máquina de Vetores de Suporte](http://www.icmc.usp.br/CMS/Arquivos/arquivos_enviados/BIBLIOTECA_113_RT_192.pdf) com um kernel não-linear (polinomial ou RBF). Há [um exemplo do scikit-learn aqui](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_svm_regression.html#example-svm-plot-svm-regression-py).

Comment: Desde já obrigado pela resposta!

Eu tenho informação acerca de 2~3 dias. Assim sendo como deverei proceder ao treino, uma vez que, o que é passado (para treino) são os segundos que passaram desde a meia noite desse dia.

Comment: Por nada. :) Como eu citei na minha resposta, você pode converter a sua data completa para o número de segundos desde o *epoch* (veja o link para a página do SOen que eu referenciei).

Comment: Fiz uma edição (o P.S.2) com informações para o caso do seu problema não ser linear (o que, intuitivamente, me parece ser o caso).

Comment: Já tinha andado a espreitar o SVR pois sabia que o problema não seria linear ... No entanto estou a obter erros grandes o que pressuponho que seja por não ter encontrado os parâmetros C e Gamma ideais e ter um dataset para treino pequeno. Será que me poderia responder às seguintes perguntas?

1. É possível treinar um modelo com falhas nos dados, ou seja, haver períodos de tempo sem medições? É provável que o resultado não seja muito bom, certo?

2. É possível encontrar os melhores parâmetros para o SVR com o StratifiedKFold e o GridSearchCV? (continua)

Comment: Eu uso o código disponível <a href="http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_rbf_parameters.html" title="exemplo">aqui</a>. Pergunto porque uso o kfold, supostamente para melhor validar os resultados, mas não sei se neste caso é apropriado pois o dataset é uma timeseries.

Uma vez mais, obrigado!!

Comment: O seu link tá quebrado. Sobre o erro, pode ser que você tenha poucos exemplos pra treinamento ou realmente pode ser um uso de C não muito apropriado. O parâmetro C define o quão ajustado o hiperplano (a superfície de decisão encontrada) vai ser aos dados de treinamento. Se você usar um valor muito grande, ele vai ajustar o modelo muito mais para os seus dados de treinamento, e talvez perde a capacidade de representação mais geral.

Comment: Dá uma lida [nesse link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_rbf_parameters.html) e note no exemplo visual variando o gamma e o C, como as regiões de classificação (em azul e vermelho) são alteradas para os mesmos dados de exemplo. No seu caso, acho que vc vai ter mesmo que fazer alguns testes e observações como essa.

Comment: Era esse o link que tentei enviar. Nessa página tem um código mais especificamente uma parte que diz Train classifier. Aí são encontrados os melhores parâmetros para o modelo da SVM. Eu mudei de SVM para SVR mas notei que é usado o StratifiedKFold. Neste caso posso usar este método? Isto porque o dataset é uma timeseries e o stratifiedKFold vai partir o dataset em treino e teste não tendo em conta a relação temporal(certo??). A outra dúvida que tinha:É possível treinar um modelo com falhas nos dados, ou seja, haver períodos de tempo sem medições? É provável que o resultado não seja bom, certo?

Comment: Eu não conheço muito de *time series forecast*, mas pelo que eu já li Redes Neurais e Cadeias Ocultas de Markov parece ser mais utilizados. Porém, acredito que um SVM deve funcionar bem se você tiver dados de exemplo significativos (falhas seguramente impactarão na predição). Há que testar. O K-Fold é apenas utilizado nesse exemplo pra estimar os melhores gamma e C a partir de vários testes. E vc tem razão, ele deixa muitos exemplos de fora. Pra minimizar isso, você pode usar o [Leave-One-Out](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#leave-one-out-loo) ao invés do KFold.

Answer (score 3):

Vejo basicamente dois modos mais ou menos simples para resolver este problema: método dos mínimos quadrados e máxima verossimilhança:

**Máxima Verossimilhança**

Uma abordagem para o seu problema é considerar a temperatura como uma variável aleatória `t`:

```
t ~ T(x, k)
```

Ou seja, `t` é variável aleatória com distribuição `T` e parâmetros `k`, sendo `x` o tempo.

`t` é o que você quer prever, `x` é o tempo que no caso seria `tempo atual + 30 minutos`, e `k` é um conjunto de 1 ou mais parâmetros desconhecidos da sua distribuição.

Observando uma amostra de valores de temperatura em função do tempo, você pode fazer uma análise superficial de como os valores se comportam e então escolher a sua função de distribuição `T`. Existem muitas distribuições, e as mais comuns são: uniforme, Poisson, exponencial, binomial, Bernoulli, Beta, Gamma. Cada uma é mais indicada para um caso específico (seria um artigo descrever cada uma delas!).

Uma vez escolhida a distribuição, você terá de definir os parâmetros da distribuição (cada distribuição exige parâmetros diferentes). Para obter estes parâmetros o método mais simples é o da Máxima Verossimilhança (MVS), mas poderia ser utilizado Bayes também.

Recomendo que utilize um livro de estatística para entender o método, ou uma biblioteca que já implemente ele pronta (não sei de nenhuma para indicar).

**Métodos dos Mínimos Quadrados**

Geralmente ensinado nas disciplinas de Métodos Numéricos ou Cálculo Numérico em cursos superiores de engenharia, ele consiste em observar o comportamento dos valores em um gráfico (no caso da temperatura em função do tempo) e identificar visualmente um comportamento para se construir uma função qualquer, que pode ser de primeiro grau, ou de segundo ou qualquer outro (inclusive não necessariamente um polinômio).

Supondo uma função do primeiro grau, podemos dizer que:

```
t = aX + E
```

Sendo `t` o valor observado, `X` o tempo do valor observado, `a` coeficiente desconhecido e `E` o erro. Ou seja, estamos aproximando o valor observado por uma função do primeiro grau mais o erro.

Nosso objetivo então é encontrar `a` que minimize a somatória dos erros quadráticos em cada valor da amostra. Ou seja:

```
t - aX = 0
```

Derivando e igualando a `0` e resolvendo o sistema formado, pode-se encontrar o valor de `a`. É necessário então derivar novamente a função para identificar se `a` é o ponto de mínimo ou de máximo.

Acredito que estes sejam os métodos mais simples para resolver o problema, mas devem existir outros (não sou matemático). Com certeza, várias bibliotecas já os implementam, mas não às conheço, uma vez que só utilizei estes métodos em provas da universidade.

Espero ter ajudado!